# idempotency and store with notify

Tags: transaction

I would like to ask what is a prefered way when you have such a code, (this is distributed transaction since I cannot delete the item and publishToKafka atomically), and I don't want to have event sourcing right now:

```
if(exists(Item))
   DeleteItem(Item)
   PublishEventKafka(ItemDeleted)
```

Now obviously if a crash is between DeleteItem then in the event of restart the PublishEventKafka is not called because `if(exists)` returns `false`.

I was also thinking about:

```
if(exists(Item))
   PublishEventKafka(ItemDeleted)
   DeleteItem(Item)
```

This, however, is a lie because the item is still there, so my conclusion was:

```
if(exists(Item) || DeleteInProgress(Item))
   DeleteItem(Item, InProgress)
   PublishEventKafka(ItemDeleted)
   DeleteItem(Item, Finish)
```

Ie I would change the state of the object to "deleting" and after it was sent I would delete the actual item. Others would also think it's deleted if they tried to read Item...

Anyway, I think there is a more generic way to solve this kind of problem or isn't there?

Comment: `Now obviously if a crash is between DeleteItem` not necessarily between. The `PublishEventKafka`might fail as well. Then what? if you want it to be idempotent, remove the `if (exist)` and condition the publication to the result of `DeleteItem`. `Delete` commands can be idempotent.

Comment: Yes but then something can spam my system... calling DeleteItems on non existing items... and it would trigger events..

Comment: AFter the item is deleted, the next call won't trigger any event `if(DeleteItem(item)){ PublishEventKafka(ItemDeleted) }`

Comment: Yes well thats what I wrote... in the original description...

Comment: `if exist` is not exactly the same that `if deletion finished`.

Comment: Ok let me explain... DeleteItem(InProgress) I meant that flag the item that it is there but it's flagged as if it is deleted (set some removed=1) but its not physically deleted.  If exists(Item) would still return true